# change default hyperlink properties in custom tag

Tags: html, css

I've got the following.. http://jsfiddle.net/JcLx4/31/ how would I change the properties of the hyperlinked text in this example from blue and underlined to black and not underlined?

Comment: As a side question, how would I hyperlink the entire line? and not just the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a very basic level, like this:

```
a:link
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To make it specific to links within your custom tag (incorporating `display:block` to make your link stretch the width of its container):

```
ab.s a:link   
{   
    color: #000;   
    display: block;     
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

And to change the hover style:

```
ab.s a:hover
{
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff; 
}
```

If you want more  information there is a tutorial on [this page](http://www.projectseven.com/tutorials/css/pseudoclasses/index.htm) that explains the different pseudo-classes.

Comment: As a side question, how would I hyperlink the entire line? and not just the text?

Comment: In the same way as your other question about the background -     add `display: block;` to your `a:link` definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
ab.s a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
}
```